# Problem with sessions, subdomains and authlogic in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, authlogic, wildcard-subdomain, subdomain-fu

I've got a rails app with authlogic authentication and a username.domain.com structure built with subdomain-fu.

But my session breaks when going from domain.com to username.domain.com. I've tried to add

```
config.action_controller.session = {:domain => '.localhost:3000'}
```

to my development.rb but that seams to break authlogic disabling sign out/sign in.

Any suggestions on what to do?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are having this issue in the development mode but probably wont have this issue in prod mode.. you are trying to set the top level cookie. your browser wont let you do that. what you are trying to do with

```
config.action_controller.session = {:domain => '.localhost:3000'}
```

is as good as saying

```
config.action_controller.session = {:domain => '.com'}
```

try creating custom local domain like localhost.localdomain or dummylocal.com or something and that will make it work.

```
config.action_controller.session = {:domain => 'localhost.localdomain'}
config.action_controller.session = {:domain => 'dummylocal.com'}
```

Answer (score 1):

For Rails3 the code above will raise `NoMethodError`:

```
undefined method `session=' for ActionController::Base:Class
```

So, for Rails3 you should not change you environment config but should set your `app/config/initializers/session_store.rb` to look like:

```
YourAppName::Application.config.session_store :active_record_store,
    {:key => '_your_namespace_session', :domain => '.yourdomain.com'}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this can help: http://erikonrails.snowedin.net/?p=248 ?